# How to create multiple pthreads with a for loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

This should be a simple task, but I just can't get it to work. The following code should be fairly self explanatory, I'm trying to create 4 threads that each print a different string from the array I defined in printMessage.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void *printMessage(void *arg)
{
   int argInt = *((int*) arg);

   const char* my_messages[4] = {"English: Hello!", 
    "French: Bonjour!", "Spanish: Hola!", 
    "German: Guten Tag!" };

   cout << my_messages[argInt] << "\n";
   pthread_exit(0);
}


int main()
{
   pthread_t id[4];

   int rc;

   // Create thread(s)
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      int index = i;
      rc = pthread_create(&id[index], NULL, printMessage, (void*) &index);
      
      if (rc) {
          cout << "ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is " << rc << endl;
          return -1;
      }
   }


   pthread_exit(0);
}
```

When this is executed, the last string in the array, "German: Guten Tag!" is printed 4 times. Another strange occurrence I noted is if I forgo the seemingly redundant 'index' variable and use 'i' instead, nothing prints. As someone who's new to c++ and multithreading, this is very confusing to me and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: <O/T> Consider using [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) rather than pthreads if you're using C++11 or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining `int index` as a local variable inside of the loop body, so it will go out of scope after `pthread_create()` exits, thus `printMessage()` is exhibiting *undefined behavior* by accessing invalid memory (the memory is likely being reused on each loop iteration).

You need to either:

- move the `index` value into an array declared before the loop, and kept in scope until all of the threads have terminated.  Like you are doing with the `id[]` array.

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void* printMessage(void *arg)
{
   int argInt = *static_cast<int*>(arg);

   const char* my_messages[4] = {"English: Hello!", 
    "French: Bonjour!", "Spanish: Hola!", 
    "German: Guten Tag!" };

   cout << my_messages[argInt] << "\n";

   return NULL;
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t id[4];
   int index[4];
   int rc, num = 0;

   // Create thread(s)
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      index[i] = i;
      rc = pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, printMessage, &index[i]);
      if (rc) {
          cout << "ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is " << rc << endl;
          break;
      }
      ++num;
   }

   // wait for threads to terminate ...
   for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       pthread_join(id[i], NULL);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

- pass the *value* of `index` into each thread, rather than passing a *pointer* to `index`.

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void* printMessage(void *arg)
{
   int argInt = reinterpret_cast<int>(arg);

   const char* my_messages[4] = {"English: Hello!", 
    "French: Bonjour!", "Spanish: Hola!", 
    "German: Guten Tag!" };

   cout << my_messages[argInt] << "\n";

   return NULL;
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t id[4];
   int rc, num = 0;

   // Create thread(s)
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      rc = pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, printMessage, reinterpret_cast<void*>(i));
      if (rc) {
          cout << "ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is " << rc << endl;
          break;
      }
      ++num;
   }

   // wait for threads to terminate ...
   for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       pthread_join(id[i], NULL);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

- allocate the `index` dynamically, and let the thread destroy the `int` it is passed.

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void* printMessage(void *arg)
{
   int *argInt = static_cast<int*>(arg);

   const char* my_messages[4] = {"English: Hello!", 
    "French: Bonjour!", "Spanish: Hola!", 
    "German: Guten Tag!" };

   cout << my_messages[*argInt] << "\n";
   delete argInt;

   return NULL;
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t id[4];
   int rc, num = 0;

   // Create thread(s)
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      int *index = new int(i);
      rc = pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, printMessage, index);
      if (rc) {
          cout << "ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is " << rc << endl;
          delete index;
          break;
      }
      ++num;
   }

   // wait for threads to terminate ...
   for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       pthread_join(id[i], NULL);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

That being said, you really should be using [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead of `pthreads` directly (let the `std::thread` implementation use `pthreads` internally, if it wants to):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void printMessage(int arg)
{
   const char* my_messages[4] = {"English: Hello!", 
    "French: Bonjour!", "Spanish: Hola!", 
    "German: Guten Tag!" };

   cout << my_messages[arg] << "\n";
}

int main()
{
   thread thrd[4];

   // Create thread(s)
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      thrd[i] = thread(printMessage, i);
   }

   // wait for threads to terminate ...
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       thrd[i].join();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
  rc = pthread_create(&id[index], NULL, printMessage, (void*) &index);
```

This creates a new execution thread, and passes to it, as its argument, a pointer to a local variable named `index`.

You have absolutely no guarantees, whatsoever, that the new execution thread actually starts executing before `pthread_create` returns, or ***promptly thereafter***.  Typically there's a small delay before a new execution thread gets into gear. All you're guaranteed is that the new execution thread will start running, *real soon now*.

Meanwhile, `pthread_create()` returns, reaches the end of the loop, and the `index` variable, to which the pointer was passed, gets destroyed and it disappears into a black hole never to be seen again. Sometime later the new execution thread starts churning, gets its thread argument, which now points to a destroyed object. Undefined behavior.

You have several options.

1. Use `new` to allocate the thread parameter in dynamic scope (and have the execution thread `delete` the `new`ed object after it's done with it).
2. Employ additional multithreaded resources, such as mutex and condition variables, to coordinate the song-and-dance involved in creating a new execution thread, so that the parent execution thread waits until the new execution thread reads its parameter, and has it at hand.